# Find text between know pattern

Tags: c#, regex, find, pattern-matching

I have a webpage source code which has several occurrences of

`<div class="detName">some unpredictable text</div>`

I want to be able to get a colleection of all `some unpredictable text`.

I tried something like:

```
var match = Regex.Match(pageSourceCode, @"<div class='detName'>/(A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\</div>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But had no success, what would be a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284240) use regex to parse HTML, you can use [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
string html = "<div class=\"detName\">some unpredictable text</div>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'detName')]");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(pageSourceCode, @"(?<=<div class='detName'>)(.*)(?=</div>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```